# Convergence of orthogonal projections

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $a_m$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$, is a sequence of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space converging strongly to an bounded linear operator $a$.  If U is a finite-dimensional subspace of H, is it true that the orthogonal projections $P_{a_m(U)} : H \rightarrow a_m(U)$ converge strongly to the orthogonal projection $P_{a(U)}$?

My impression is that this is true.  However, I'm unable to prove it.  Any help would be appreciated.